# Vector Space as Direct Sum of Kernels

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$. Let $\psi : V \longrightarrow V$ be a linear operator. Let $p(t)=f_{1}(t)^{k_{1}} \cdots f_{m}(t)^{k_{m}}$ be the characteristic polynomial of $\psi$ with $f_{1}(t)^{k_{1}}, \cdots ,f_{m}(t)^{k_{m}}$ irreducible polynoms. Prove that $V=Ker(f_{1}(\psi))\oplus \cdots \oplus Ker(f_{m}(\psi))$.

Okay, so far I'm able to show that $Ker(f_{i}(\psi)) \cap Ker(f_{j}(\psi))=\{0\}$ for every $i\neq j$, so the direct sum is valid. And I know that if $p(t)$ itself is irreducible, then the statement can be proven simply by Cayley-Hamilton Theorem (which says $p(\psi)v=0$ for every $v\in V$).

I also know that $Ker(f_{i}(\psi))$ is a $\psi$-invariant subspace. I think that's important since there's a theorem that says if $V=W_{1}\oplus \cdots \oplus W_{m}$ with $W_{1}, \cdots ,W_{m}$ $T$-invariant subspaces, then the characteristic polynomial of $T$ is $p(T)=f_{1}(t)\cdots f_{m}(t)$ with $f_{i}(t)$ is the characteristic polynom of $T_{W_{i}}$ ($T_{W_{i}}$ is the linear operator $T$ restricted to $W_{i}$).

And now I'm stuck.

Comment: Stuck on what? At the end of the 2nd §, the assertion (which is the kernels decomposition lemma, incidentally) is proved.